# How to open a folder/Directory in Java

Tags: java, file, directory

I have a TilePane with a `imageView` items, each imageview displaying an image got from a directory in my pc. When any of the images in the `tilePane` is clicked  a message is printed onto console with the direcory path address to the folder where the image resides, for example:

```
You clicked: ImageResources/wp.png
```

I would like to extend this further so that when a particular image is clicked the folder in which the image resides opens.

My implementation below only prints to console the message below, but no directory/ folder gets opened. The message is:

```
File Not Found
```

How can I get it to work so that the folder|directory opens? Thank you all in advance.

Also, of the directory could open with the clicked image selected, then that would be an extra, but is not a priority right now.

My implementation so far goes as follows:

```
public class TilePaneExample extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        VBox root = new VBox(30);

        String[] imageResources = new String[]{
            //loading images
            "ImageResources/facebook.png",
            "ImageResources/faviicon.png",
            "ImageResources/jquery-logo.png",
            "ImageResources/linkedin_32.png",
            "ImageResources/loading1.png",
            "ImageResources/twitter.png",
            "ImageResources/twitter_32.png",
            "ImageResources/wp.png",};

        // Pane
        TilePane tilePane = new TilePane();
        tilePane.setHgap(5);
        tilePane.setVgap(5);

        for (final String imageResource : imageResources) {
            Image image = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream(imageResource));
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);
            imageView.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                    File f = new File(imageResource);
                    String absolutePath = f.getAbsolutePath();
                    String folderPath = absolutePath.
                            substring(0, absolutePath.lastIndexOf(File.separator));
                    try {
                        Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File(folderPath));
                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
                        System.out.println("File Not Found");
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(TilePaneExample.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }
            });
            tilePane.getChildren().add(imageView);
        }

        root.getChildren().addAll(tilePane);
        primaryStage.setTitle("TilePane Example");
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 150);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `folderPath` in runtime?

Comment: For example, clicking the second image, `"ImageResources/faviicon.png"`, prints its folder path as `D:\standAloneDev\java\workingDir\Jive\TilePaneExample\ImageResources`, @Pphoenix

Comment: maybe the message of `IllegalArgumentException iae` shows you what the problem is. try `iae.printStackTrace()` instead of your sysout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, clicking the second image, "ImageResources/faviicon.png", prints its folder path as D:\standAloneDev\java\workingDir\Jive\TilePaneExample\ImageResources